# Unexpected output with boost coroutine2

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++14, boost-coroutine

This is the test case

```
#include <boost/coroutine2/all.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    auto sum = 0;
    using Coroutine_t = boost::coroutines2::coroutine<int>::push_type;
    auto coro = Coroutine_t{[&](auto& yield) {
        for (;;) {
            auto val = yield.get();
            std::cout << "Currently " << val << std::endl;
            sum += val;
            yield(); // jump back to starting context
         }
    }};

    std::cout << "Transferring 1" << std::endl;
    coro(1); // transfer {1} to coroutine-function
    std::cout << "Transferring 2" << std::endl;
    coro(2); // transfer {1} to coroutine-function

    // assert(sum == 3);
}
```

For some reason the assert at the end fails with the value of sum being `14`  I installed boost (version 1.63) context with the command

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=build --with-libraries=context
./b2 --prefix=build --with-context
```

I am running this on a MacOS `10.12.6`.  The compile command was

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O3 -I boost co.cpp boost/stage/lib/libboost_*.a
```

Where `boost` is the boost folder downloaded from sourceforge.

The output of the above test case strangely without the `assert` is this

```
Transferring 1
Currently 0
Transferring 2
Currently 2
Currently 2
```

Why is the first line printed in the coroutine `Currently 0`?  Also why is `Currently 2` is printed twice here??  The latter can be seen here as well https://wandbox.org/permlink/zEL9fGT5MrzWGgQB

---

For the second question it seems like after the main thread has finished, control is transferred back to the coroutine one last time.  Why is that?  That seems strange..

UPDATE : For the second question, it seems to be different in boost 1.65??!? https://wandbox.org/permlink/JQa9Wq1jp8kB49Up

Comment: Regarding the second question. Why is it strange? One could argue that ending the co-routine object's lifetime should give the routine one last chance to run.

Comment: @StoryTeller then what happens when you have `n` coroutines?  Do they still continue running after main even though the main thread has finished?  For example assume that an exception was thrown from somewhere in main, caught at the top level and then `return 1` to show an error.  But there are lots of intertwined coroutines that ran at one point, do they all still keep running as if everything is normal until they hit a terminating point (if they hit a terminating point) even after main returns?  That seems strange right?

Comment: @StoryTeller It seems to work as expected in boost 1.65 (WOT).  See my updated question

Comment: Are you saying you find it strange that bugs get fixed?

Comment: @sehe I don't know whether this is a bug or not, this seems to be one of the most staightforward use cases of coroutines, so my gut feeling is that this is somehow not a bug..

Comment: It could be. Have you tried Boost 1.65.1? There were some bugs fixed that were stoppers for - I think - consumers of Boost Context and further downstream. I haven't checked the specifics.

Comment: @sehe 1.65.1 has the expected result on macs, although I still don't know if the previous result is a bug or just something that should be expected.

Answer (score 0):

output of your app with boost-1.65.1 is:

```
Transferring 1
Currently 1
Transferring 2
Currently 2
```

probably your problem was caused by bug that has been fixed in boost-1.63